# Wordpress: Custom posts permalinks

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have a problem. I thought wordpress would be smart enough to handle this. Anyways...I am using a static frontpage and my blog posts on a page called "Newsroom". Everything is working, but not as I like to have it.

By doing this I hoped that the posts permalink would be like /newsroom/2012/... but they're still the regular /2012/01/26/post-name. How can I make this work?

Current permalink structure: **/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/**

Blog posts index: **/newsroom**

The reason why I can't just put newsroom in my permalink structure is because I have custom post types that shouldn't be affected.

Answer (score 0):

change your permalink to /%category/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

also in your category base put /. that will make it so it doesn't always say www.url.com/category/newsroom/...

Comment: That adds the posts category, not the page name which is newsroom. Also I can't do this: /newsroom/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/ because I have custom post types that shouldn't have newsroom in front.

Comment: ahhh, you could set up a specific page called newsroom, then apply a template to it maybe?

Comment: That's exactly what I did, followed an tutorial from wordpress.org.

Comment: what about using /%postname%/%monthnum%/%day%/ putting the postname to the front...

Comment: The postname is not newsroom, the postname is the title of the post.